# changing loop type to get rid of inefficiencies

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
public class test2
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int mark;
        int sum = 0;
        int student = 1;
        for (student = 1; student <= 10; student++)
        {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("enter mark");
            mark = sc.nextInt();
            if (mark > 0)
            {
                sum = sum + mark;
            }

            else
            {
                student = 50;
            }

        }
        System.out.println("sum is" + sum);

    }
}
```

i want to change this code to better suit the purpose and get rid of any inefficiencies i think while loop would work better than if else loop but i dont know how to approach this problem.

Comment: I guess this is wrong statement `student = 50;` because your loop will exit immediately. It is not clear what you are exactly is the problem you are facing.

Comment: sorry for any confusion what i wanted to do in this code is sum up the marks if its greater than 0 and exit the loop if 0 is input. because this is not efficient i wanted to change to a different loop type to make it more clear, but didnt have any idea where to start.@YoungHobbit

Comment: Your loop speed is dependent on human interaction.  What kind of efficiency are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

1. Declare the Scanner outside the loop. (You have to call `sc.nextLine()` after each call to `nextInt()`)
2. Do you use `student = 50;` to exit your loop? That's what `break` is for.
3. Your loopchoice doesn't really effect efficiency. A for loop seems appropiate for this.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your method as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int mark;
    int sum = 0;
    int student = 1;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (student <= 10) {
        System.out.println("Enter mark: ");
        mark = sc.nextInt();
        if (mark != 0) {        // check if mark is not 0
            sum = sum + mark;   // increment the mark
        } else {
            break;              // exit the loop 
        }
        student++;
    }
    System.out.println("Sum is: " + sum);
}
```

Then if you enter mark `0`, it will immediately quits the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
public class test2
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // Declare outside loop, you only need one instance
        for (int student = 1; student <= 10; student++)
        {
            System.out.println("enter mark");
            int mark = sc.nextInt();
            if (mark <= 0) // If mark is negative
            {
                break; // Exit loop
            }
            sum += mark; // Increment sum by mark

        }
        System.out.println("sum is" + sum);
    }
}
```

I think mark of 0 should be a valid input though so you might want to use `mark < 0' instead